# Easy-to-clean Flux for soldering vacuum seals

Tags: vacuum, brazing, soldering

If using solder to seal high and medium vacuum fittings made of brass, bronze, or stainless, are there any types of flux that are easier to clean than others to prevent vacuum contamination? I am only familiar with electronic rosin and no clean fluxes which are tenacious without physical agitation which may not always be possible inside a fitting, but maybe there are more non-electronic fluxes that are easier to clean.

Comment: There are many types of flux, some might be better suited than others. Some are in liquid form others in a paste form. You will need to check and investigate which might suit your application better.